# Commuting matrices

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to construct an inverse of an operator and it relies on whether I can prove if two matrices commute.

Given a matrix function: $A:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, I'm trying to show that

$\left(\int_0^t A(\xi) d \xi \right) A(t)=A(t)\left(\int_0^t A(\xi) d \xi \right)$.

This obviously depends on the fact if $A(t)A(\xi)=A(\xi)A(t)$, because if this is true, then

$\left(\int_0^t A(\xi) d \xi \right) A(t)=\left(\int_0^t A(\xi)A(t) d \xi \right) =\left(\int_0^t A(t)A(\xi) d \xi \right) =A(t)\left(\int_0^t A(\xi) d \xi \right)$.

Thus, the only thing to be proven is $A(t)A(\xi)=A(\xi)A(t)$.

This is obviously true for the scalar case, and I ran some random matrices in MATLAB and it was true for them as well. Thus, I think that it maight be true but I don't know how to prove of disprove. Perhaps, I should just roll up my sleeves and just use the definition of matrix multiplication to try and prove it. If there's any other easier/elegant method, I would be most thankful.

Regards,

Comment: I edited your post to distinguish your variables. You should not use the same variable in your limits of integration as you do for your integration variable. Integration variables are local variables.

Comment: It really depends more on the function $A(t)$. For example, if $B,C$ are matrices that do not commute, define $A(t)=tB+(1-t)C$. Then $A(1)=B$ and $A(0)=C$ do not commute.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to show that for all $t,\xi\;A(t)A(\xi)=A(\xi)A(t)$. This is not true in general. Is there any assumption on $A:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

Comment: This is most definitely not true in general. What conditions do you have on $A$?

Comment: Hi Cameron, I've edited my post. Indeed, it was a mistake by me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Amitai and Cameron, yes, that's what I wih to prove. The only property of $A$ is that its entries are rational functions.

Comment: @Amit: That is a big 'only'.

Comment: @copper.hat: Kindly elaborate, I'm unable to understand how the elements being rational has a bearing.

Comment: @Amit, the statement is false even for the simple case $A(t) = B + tC$ with $[B,C] \ne 0$. Perhaps you should tell us a little bit more about your original problem and how those $A(t)$ are defined.

Comment: @Amit: Well, its an extra constraint that affects any counterexamples. People are trying to help, if you add conditions after they have answered it is a little frustrating.

Comment: @achillehui: Indeed, it is evident now that the statement is false. But if you need know, $A(t)=D(t)^{-1}B(t)$, where $D(t)$ is a strictly positive scalar polynomial and $B(t)$ is a matrix whose entries are scalar polynomials.

Comment: @copper.hat: In that case, I'll apologize. I should have added the complete description, without leaving out the information that I thought would not be important.

Comment: @Amit: No problem, in this case it is not a problem to modify the original counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Note that $M M^T \ne M^T M$.

Let $A(t) = M 1_{[0,{1 \over 2})} (t) + M^T 1_{[{1 \over 2}, 1]} (t)$.

Then $\int_0^{1 \over 2} A(t) dt = {1 \over 2} M$, $A({1 \over 2}) = M^T$ and so they don't commute.

It should be clear that we can modify $A(\cdot)$ on some small interval
$({1 \over 2}-\epsilon, {1 \over 2})$ so that $A$ is continuous and the condition $A({1 \over 2}) \int_0^{1 \over 2} A(t) dt \neq \int_0^{1 \over 2} A(t) dt A({1 \over 2})$ still remains true.

Since the polynomials are dense in $C[0,1]$, we can uniformly approximate $A$ by a sequence of matrices $A_n$ whose entries are polynomials. For sufficiently large $n$, the condition will be violated.

Comment: Is this a counterexample?

Comment: @Nishant: It is a counterexample to the statement that $A(t)$ and $A(s)$ commute, and also to the statement that $A(t)$ and $\int_0^t A(s) ds$ commute.